# Border for thick lines in R plotting

Tags: r, plot

The picture below explains what I'd like to achieve in R. The blue line is added with a simple call to `lines`. This line shows some values of parameter over time. The line is thick (`lwd=3`) so it can be seen at a low zoom, and also so that the individual data points fit inside of it. This means that it overlaps with itself when there is chatter over a small x interval. Can the line be made to have a border to better resolve areas with overlap?

[image]

Comment: Please make this reproducible: small sample data, code you've tried, packages you intend (base R, `ggplot2`, `lattice`, `plotly`, ...).

Comment: @r2evans any data set whatsoever, base R. `plot(seq(0,10),seq(0,10),cex=0); lines(seq(0,10),seq(0,10),lwd=3,col="blue")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a thicker line first and then draw thinner line on top of it

```
set.seed(42)
x = 1:10
y = sample(1:10)

plot(x, y, type = "l", lwd = 5, col = "red")
lines(x, y, lwd = 3, col = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: ... it would be nice for `lines` and/or `geom_lines` to have `border=` and `fill=` arguments :-)

Comment: I've used this trick you showed a few times, unfortunately it is subject to width-control and scaling (dpi) challenges. And while I've thought about trying to remedy it, it's not been enough priority to spend time on it ... so I'm just as guilty :-)

Comment: Oh, that's a nice trick. I was trying to draw thin lines along the edges of the thick line, then realized I'd be reimplementing `line` by the time I specified coordinates for the outline...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative.

Under the assumption that seeing borders *in order* and on top of the "fill" color is important, then borrowing from d.b's excellent, fast, and very-simple answer that intersections give no indication of which direction came first (left of the 3-pack, below).

Altered data, to show overlaps:

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(10)
y <- sample(10)
```

One solution is to draw each segment individually, controlling colors each time.

```r
segments2 <- function(x, y, lwd = c(2, 1), ..., border = NA, fill = NA) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
  len <- length(x)
  ign <- Map(function(x0, y0, x1 = x0, y1 = y0) {
    if (!is.na(border)) lines(c(x0, x1), c(y0, y1), lwd = lwd[1], col = border, ...)
    if (!is.na(fill)) lines(c(x0, x1), c(y0, y1), lwd = lwd[2], col = fill, ...)
  }, x[-len], y[-len], x[-1], y[-1])
  invisible()
}
```

This produces the middle plot below, but notice that each vertex has border-intrusion. A third option, much more complex, can mitigate that with a lot of trickery.

```r
segments3 <- function(x, y, lwd = c(2, 1), ..., border = NA, fill = NA, lend = 0) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
  len <- length(x)
  dx <- x[-len] + diff(x) / 2
  mx <- rbind(
    c(NA, x[1], dx[1]),
    cbind(dx[-(len-1)], x[-c(1,len)], dx[-c(1)]))
  mx <- rbind(
    mx[-(len-1),],
    c(x[len], dx[len-1], NA),
    mx[len-1,])
  dy <- y[-len] + diff(y) / 2
  my <- rbind(
    c(NA, y[1], dy[1]),
    cbind(dy[-(len-1)], y[-c(1,len)], dy[-c(1)]))
  my <- rbind(
    my[-(len-1),],
    c(y[len], dy[len-1], NA),
    my[len-1,])
  for (rn in seq_len(nrow(mx))) {
    lend0 <- if (rn %in% c(1L, len-1)) lend else 1
    lines(mx[rn,], my[rn,], lwd = lwd[1], col = border, ..., lend = lend0)
    lines(mx[rn,], my[rn,], lwd = lwd[2], col = fill, ..., lend = lend0)
  }
}
```

It is likely possible to simplify this, but its performance is not heinous, and it does produce a slightly clearer plot.

```r
par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
# simpler method
plot(x, y, type = "l", lwd = 5, col = "red", main = "Simpler")
lines(x, y, lwd = 3, col = "green")
# slower method, full-size
plot(x, y, type = "n", main = "Slower")
segments2(x, y, lwd = c(5, 3), border="red", fill="green")
# slowest method, fairly complex
plot(x, y, type = "n", main = "Slowest")
segments3(x, y, lwd = c(5, 3), border="red", fill="green")
```

[image: three pack of various alternatives]

Some notes:

- `lwd` is a length-2 vector used to control the widths of the two lines; perhaps it would be more intuitive to have `lwd` be the main line and `border.lwd` be the border's thickness?
- `...` arguments are passed through to `lines`, except
- `lend`, which is tightly-controlled in order to keep mid-segment line endings controller but allow the user to override the two ends
- if either `border` or `fill` are `NA`, then they just won't be drawn, which would then make one question why using this function
- depending on your perspective, dimensions, etc, it is possible that a segment mid-point hints at a little junction, which can be seen as a hint in the left-most segment around (1.8, 3.7) ... this can go away just be resizing, and is I believe just an artifact of raster graphics in general

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to work through the "slowest" example when I have free time.